# Lenovo m720q Intel i915 Video Problems with 22.04 and 24.04

Tags: 22.04, video, intel, i915, 24.04

I'm moving from a Lenovo m700q (i5-6400T) to an m720q (i5-9500T). I've tried both cloning my 22.04 install and attempting it on m720q, and also attempted a fresh install of a 24.04 nightly and ended up in the same place. The display looks the same on both Ubuntu versions on the newer hardware (m720q)

Install of 24.04 went fine in safe mode (nomodeset), but upon reboot, the screen looked pixelated and resolution was bad and hard to read. There are two pics below from those two different systems - tiny, clear pixels are from the m700q and the lower resolution, blurry is the m720q.

New hardware - m720q:

[image: New hardware - m720q]

Old Hardware - m700q:

[image: Old Hardware - m700q]

New System:

```
# grep 'i915\|drm\|intel\.' /var/log/syslog | awk '{ $2="Host"; print $0 }'
2024-03-24T19:16:31.159307+00:00 Host kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-11-generic root=UUID=3bbe2170-8736-48fe-9779-f291e3775f70 ro enable_fbc=1 i915.enable_guc=2 splash vt.handoff=7
2024-03-24T19:16:31.159545+00:00 Host kernel: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-11-generic root=UUID=3bbe2170-8736-48fe-9779-f291e3775f70 ro enable_fbc=1 i915.enable_guc=2 splash vt.handoff=7
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160077+00:00 Host kernel: ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160160+00:00 Host kernel: [drm] Initialized simpledrm 1.0.0 20200625 for simple-framebuffer.0 on minor 0
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160161+00:00 Host kernel: simple-framebuffer simple-framebuffer.0: [drm] fb0: simpledrmdrmfb frame buffer device
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160372+00:00 Host kernel: systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160444+00:00 Host kernel: systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160447+00:00 Host kernel: systemd[1]: Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160546+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160547+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: vgaarb: VGA decodes changed: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160547+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160548+00:00 Host kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_ops [i915])
2024-03-24T19:16:31.160563+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] [ENCODER:94:DDI A/PHY A] failed to retrieve link info, disabling eDP
2024-03-24T19:16:32.773000+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/kbl_guc_70.1.1.bin version 70.1.1
2024-03-24T19:16:32.773012+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/kbl_huc_4.0.0.bin version 4.0.0
2024-03-24T19:16:32.795836+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC: authenticated for all workloads
2024-03-24T19:16:32.795841+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: submission disabled
2024-03-24T19:16:32.795842+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: SLPC disabled
2024-03-24T19:16:32.820869+00:00 Host kernel: [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824936+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: display version: 9
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824937+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: cursor_needs_physical: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824937+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_cdclk_crawl: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824938+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_cdclk_squash: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824938+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_ddi: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824939+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_dp_mst: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824939+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_dsb: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824940+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_fpga_dbg: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824940+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_gmch: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824941+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_hotplug: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824941+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_hti: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824942+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_ipc: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824942+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_overlay: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824943+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_psr: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824943+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_psr_hw_tracking: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824943+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: overlay_needs_physical: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824944+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: supports_tv: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824944+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_hdcp: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824945+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_dmc: yes
2024-03-24T19:16:32.824945+00:00 Host kernel: i915 display info: has_dsc: no
2024-03-24T19:16:32.872858+00:00 Host kernel: fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
2024-03-24T19:16:32.872874+00:00 Host kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
2024-03-24T19:16:32.872877+00:00 Host kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
2024-03-24T19:16:33.613982+00:00 Host /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1254]: Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-11-generic root=UUID=3bbe2170-8736-48fe-9779-f291e3775f70 ro enable_fbc=1 i915.enable_guc=2 splash vt.handoff=7
2024-03-24T19:16:33.621472+00:00 Host /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1254]: (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
2024-03-24T19:16:33.621512+00:00 Host /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1254]: (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card1
2024-03-24T19:16:33.629860+00:00 Host /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1254]: #011915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
```

New System:

```
# lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] [8086:3e92]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Video
    Subsystem: Lenovo CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] [17aa:312d]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
--
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #6 [8086:a33d] (rev f0)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port [17aa:312d]
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a308] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:312d]
 
Old System:
# lspci -knn | grep -iEA5 'vga|3d|display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 [8086:1912] (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 530 [17aa:30d2]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a12f] (rev 31)
```

I've spent the weekend searching and haven't found any settings or options that make this work. I suspect `nomodeset` will work, but then I'll not be getting the benefits of the GPU acceleration.

The screen is a SunFounder 7 Inch TFT Monitor for Raspberry Pi, HDMI - 1024x600 HD LCD Screen.  I did try connecting the HDMI to another, larger screen and it worked fine, so could this be an X config? I also tried this config for X11.

```
    Section "Device"
      Identifier "Intel Graphics"
      Driver "intel"nomodeset
      Option      "DRI"  "iris"
    Option      "AccelMethod"  "uxa"
    Option      "TearFree"        "false"
    Option      "TripleBuffer"    "false"
    Option      "SwapbuffersWait" "false"
    EndSection
    Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "VGA-1"
        Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline  "1600x900_60.00"  118.25  1600 1696 1856 2112  900 903 908 934 -hsync +vsync
        Modeline  "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1368x768_60.00"
    EndSection
```

Comment: Ubuntu 24.04 (*noble*) doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *noble* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 18 April 2024, and isn't on-topic here until release on 25 April 2024.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *noble* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Your pasted details show the use of an *unsupported* (as currently *released*) kernel making your details invalid. If you correct the details to reflect a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS install, your question is on-topic, but your pasted details show an *alpha* install of a product that is off-topic here.